# Estimating Poincare constant for unit interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to show that the Poincare constant for the $W^{1,2}_0(0,1)$ is smaller than $1$. More specifically, I want to show that there is a constant $C<1$ such that for any $f\in C^\infty_c(0,1)$ (compactly supported smooth) we have the inequality
$$
\lVert f\rVert\leq C\lVert f'\lVert
$$
where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the $L^2$ norm.

The proof of Poincare inequality that I know (using Cauchy-Schwarz) gives an estimate of $C=2$, while the Wikipedia article seems to say that optimally $C\leq \pi^{-1}$. I'm looking for a simple proof for this special case. I don't need a very sharp estimate, just smaller than $1$, and would appreciate a hint or a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constant you are looking for is the following:
$$\tag{1}\frac{1}{C^2}=\inf\left\{ \int_0^1 \left(f'\right)^2\, dx\ :\ \int_0^1 (f)^2\, dx=1\right\}. $$
Since
$$\int_0^1 \left(f'\right)^2\, dx = \langle -f'', f\rangle, $$
you are in fact looking for the first eigenvalue of the following Sturm-Liouville problem:
$$\tag{2}\begin{cases}
-\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}=\lambda f, \\ \\f(0)=f(1)=0. \end{cases}$$

Indeed, we can now rewrite the minimization in (1) as
$$
\inf_{f\ne 0} \frac{\langle -f'', f\rangle}{\langle f, f\rangle}, $$
and this equals exactly the smallest eigenvalue of the problem (2), just like in ordinary linear algebra; see [Wikipedia on the Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

The problem (2) can be integrated explicitly and you find that the first eigenvalue is $\pi^2$ with eigenfunction $\sin(\pi x)$ (and scalar multiples of it). Therefore
$$C=\frac{1}{\pi}<1.$$

Comment: @tomasz: I don't understand your edit, care to explain? As far as I know, by minimizing the Rayleigh quotient 
$$\frac{\int_0^1 \lvert f'\rvert^2\, dx}{\int_0^1 \lvert f\rvert^2\, dx}, $$you obtain $1/C$, not $1/C^2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are. The $L^2$ norm is the square root of integral of the square.

Comment: Oh well, right. I didn't notice that you take square roots. I was referring to the following constant: $$\int f^2\le C \int \lvert \nabla f \rvert^2.$$

Comment: Well, I just corrected it so that it actually refers to the one I asked about. Nothing important, but still could be a source of confusion for someone else looking for the answer. :)

Comment: what is the relationship between the first eigenvalue of Sturm-Liouville problem with $\int_0^1 \left(f'\right)^2\, dx = \langle -f'', f\rangle$??

Comment: @user253963: Edited to explain that.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. +10 :)