# Prove $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\le\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2dx$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is dericative  and continuous on $[0,1]$, $f(0)=f(1)=0$, Prove
>   $$\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\le\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2dx$$

Tried to expand it as Taylor series, after trying some different points , still don't know how to connect $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: This is Poincaré inequality

Comment: @ZacharySelk Is there an effective version of the inequality? It is true that $L^{2}$ norm of the original function can be bounded by the constant times $L^{2}$ norm of $f'$, but I can't find any reference that gives the explicit value of the constant.

Comment: @SeewooLee See for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360670/estimating-poincare-constant-for-unit-interval

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the Fourier expansion of $f(x)$:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}\sin(n\pi x). 
$$
We have 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}dx = \frac{1}{2}(a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2} +a_{3}^{2} + \cdots)
$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)^{2}dx = \frac{\pi^{2}}{2}(a_{1}^{2} + 4a_{2}^{2} + 9a_{3}^{2} + \cdots)
$$
so actually we have a stronger inequality 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2}dx \leq \frac{1}{\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)^{2}dx
$$
where the equality holds for $f(x) = c\sin(\pi x)$ for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: why $ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}dx = a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2} +a_{3}^{2} + \cdots $. How to calculate it directly?

Comment: @JaqenChou It is called Parseval's theorem. Formally, you can take a square of the Fourier expansion and use the fact that $\int_{0}^{1}\sin^{2}(n\pi x)dx = 1/2$, $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = 0$ for $n\neq m$. (I realized that we need $1/2$ on the both side. I edited.

Comment: Thanks. And why the expansion only about $\sin$ not involved $\cos$.

Comment: This is the classical proof of Wirtinger's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions)