# How to prove that $a(u,v)=\int_0^1 u'v' dx$ is coercive

Tags: normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, inner-products, finite-element-method

Let $u,v \in H^1_0 (0,1)$

$a(u, v)=\int_0^1 u^{\prime} v^{\prime} dx$

I did not understand how they established the inequality between the 2nd and 3rd line. Can someone explain it to me in detail?

$$
\begin{aligned}
a(u, u) & =\int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x \\
& \geq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[\left(u^{\prime}\right)^2+u^2\right] d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\|u\|_{H^1(0,1)}^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I didn't understand why $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 dx \geq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[\left(u^{\prime}\right)^2+u^2\right] dx $

Comment: This looks like an application of Poincare's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes, it is necessary to apply the Poincaré inequality to prove coercivity, but it is still not clear to me how the inequality was established.

Comment: I think they are assuming or have shown previously that the constant in Poincare's inequality is $\leq 1$ on this domain. The minimal Poincare constant on this domain is $1/\pi < 1$ iirc.

Comment: @whpowell96 I don’t think it’s because of this, it’s probably a relationship between the $H^1_0 (0,1)$ norm and the $L^2 (0,1)$ norm.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comments, the typical way you prove coercivity of this bilinear form is by using Poincare's inequality, which is stated generally in 1-D as $$\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C_{\Omega,p}\|u'\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\quad\forall u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega).$$ The subscripts on the constant $C>0$ are to indicate that $C$ depends only on $p$ and $\Omega$.

Coercitivity for $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is then typically shown like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a(u, u) & =\int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x \\
&\geq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left[u^{\prime}\right]^2 d x+\frac{1}{2C} \int_0^1\left[u\right]^2 d x \\
& \geq\frac{\theta}{2}\|u\|_{H^1(0,1)}^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\theta = \min\{1, 1/C \}$. Notice that this inequality was reached by dividing Poincare's inequality by $C$. That is, $$\frac{1}{C}\|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}\leq \|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}$$

The exact value of $\theta$ isn't really important as long as it is greater than zero. The conditions you have written don't contradict this as long as $C\leq 1$.

For this domain, one can actually explicitly compute the minimal value of $C$ such that the inequality is satisfied via the variational problem

$$\frac{1}{C^2} = \inf_{u\in H_0^1(0,1)}\frac{\|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2}{\|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2}.$$

This can be solved via calculus of variations or other methods to show that $C = 1/\sqrt{\lambda_1}$, where $\lambda_1 = \pi^2$ is the first (smallest) eigenvalue of the negative Laplacian, $-\Delta$, on $(0,1)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. See, for example, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360670/estimating-poincare-constant-for-unit-interval) or [this handout](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/eigenvalues.pdf) for more reading on solving this variational problem. This principle is true for any domain $\Omega$, but one can actually compute this constant easily on this domain and some other simple ones.

Answer (score 1):

To complement whpowell96's answer: you can also prove more directly that the Poincaré constant here is less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 1$ without too much effort, using Cauchy-Schwarz in the following manner:

Let $u \in H^1_0(0,1)$.
Then, for $x \in [0,1]$:
$$\begin{split}|u(x)|^2 = \left|\int_0^x u'(t)\mathrm{d}t\right|^2 &\leq \left(\int_0^x |u'(t)|\mathrm{d}t\right)^2\\ &\overset{\text{C-S}}{\leq} \left(\int_0^x |u'(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t\right)\left(\int_0^x 1^2\mathrm{d}t\right)\\ &\leq \|u'\|_{L^2}^2 \cdot x\end{split}$$

Therefore, by integrating:
$$\|u\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_0^1 |u(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_0^1 \|u'\|_{L^2}^2 x \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \|u'\|_{L^2}^2$$

Hence: $$\|u\|_{L^2} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \|u'\|_{L^2}$$

(As an aside, notice that only the fact that $u(0) = 0$ has been used, $u(1) = 0$ has not been used.)

Comment: Yes. This is the simple proof that is usually shown when first introducing Poincare and it works for all the estimates one typically needs to make since one rarely needs optimal Poincare constants for these problems.